# Show only the missing numbers

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I have two columns one has 6127 rows the other 6129 row.  These two rows should match exactly.  How do I get only the missing info in column a to show?  So I can quickly find what missing?

Answer (score 1):

In C2 put this:

```
=ISNUMBER(MATCH(B2,A:A,0))
```

Then copy/drag down:

[image]

Now filter on the third column for FALSE:

[image]

And now the visible values in Column B are the ones that are missing in Column A.

---

Note: this only works if the values in the columns are unique in that column.  It will return false positives if the values are duplicates:

You can change the formula to:

```
=COUNTIF(A:A,B2)>=COUNTIF(B:B,B2)
```

To deal with duplicates.  Though this will return all the values in B that their count does not match.

Answer (score 0):

1. I assume values are there in Column A and Column B.
2. In C2 Enter the Formula : =B2=A2
3. Copy Formula Entered in C2 down the rows.
4. In Column C You will see result as "TRUE" for every match.
5. Copy Column C and again paste the same in Column C as VALUES.
6. Now sort the worksheet on Column C ; in Descending Order to get all "FALSE"
   Entries, for further editing.
7. To maintain the reference it is always better to maintain a Serial Column, 
   generally in First Column as 1,2,3 .... So that when you sort it you get a 
   reference in the First Column for identification. 
   To get Serial Column : A1 Title : "Sr.No."
                          A2 = 1
                          A3 = A2 + 1
                  Copy Formula of A3 down the row.
                  Select Column A, Copy and then paste values in Column A
                  This will maintain the reference, even after sorting.
8. I hope you are satisfied.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If by "match exactly" you mean that values in column A should equal values in column B line for line, then this would mean that you have two blanks somewhere in column A. Select both columns and add a filter to them (in Data -> Filters or press Alt+A+F). Click the filter arrow in column A and select the (blanks).

You could also use Harshad's method but use the filter instead of sorting.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to find only two mismatches in 6000+ rows, you need a way to quickly zero in on just the mismatches.

Assuming your data is in columns A and B, this formula:

```
=MATCH(1,1*(A:A<>B:B),0)
```

will return the row number of the first mismatch.  After you correct the data, it will show the row number of the second mismatch.

If you have column headings, they are probably different, so the first mismatch in the *data* is the second overall mismatch.  This formula will find the row number of the second mismatch:

```
=SMALL(IF(((A:A<>B:B)),ROW(A:A),FALSE),2)
```

and, again, it will show the final mismatch once the first one is corrected.

The formulas above must be entered as array formulas, with CTRL-Shift Enter.